# Creating dynamic url with Blazor gives wrong reference when looping

Tags: c#, html, razor, foreach, blazor

I am creating a Blazor webassembly application and ran into an issue when looping over content to generate urls to mp3 files.

The media files are called "1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3" ... etc.

Assume you have a razor page with this content:

```asp
@* set counter variable to 1 *@
@InitCounter()

@foreach(string str in strings)
{
   <div>
       <span @onclick="() => PlayUrl(counter)">@counter</span>
       <span>@str</span>
   </div>

   @* Increment counter variable by 1 *@
   @IncrementCounter()
}

@code
{
    public int counter = 1;

    public string InitCounter()
    {
       counter = 1;
       return string.Empty;
    }

    public string IncrementCounter()
    {
       counter++;
       return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I have troubles understanding why the function `PlayUrl` is being called with the wrong value, when I click on that particular span element in the browser?

Lets says that `strings` is defined this way:

```c#
   strings[] strings = { "aaa", "bbb" };
```

This should generate some html similar to this:

```asp
<div>
  <span b-2e01zi41cp="">1</span>
  <span b-2e01zi41cp="">aaa</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span b-2e01zi41cp="">2</span>
  <span b-2e01zi41cp="">bbb</span>
</div>
```

No matter which span element that I click on, it will **always** call PlayUrl with the argument '3'.

Is there anyone that can explain why and how to make Blazor pass the right value to PlayUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (string str in strings)
{
   var localCounter = counter; // Capture the current value of counter
   <div>
       <span @onclick="() => PlayUrl(localCounter)">@counter</span>
       <span>@str</span>
   </div>

   @IncrementCounter()
}
```

In Blazor, when you use a lambda expression `(() => PlayUrl(counter))` inside a loop, it captures the variable `counter` by reference, not by value. This means that every `lambda expression` in your loop is referring to the `same counter variable`, which is why `PlayUrl` always receives the final value of counter after the loop has completed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm, when I made the modification. I never though there could be this kind of subtleties to lamda functions.